# Getting error while trying to merge shards using vitess

Tags: mysql, sharding, distributed-database, vitess

I have sharded a single table from a single shard(0) into two shards(-80 and 80-).
After sharding I deleted the shard 0, its tablets and recreated the shard 0 again.

I am trying to merge shards -80 and 80- to 0 but getting the following error while trying to run the splitClone command:

```
init() failed: destination shard task/0 is serving some types
```

Note: I referred https://github.com/youtube/vitess/blob/master/test/merge_sharding.py for same but not working out for me. Thanks!

Comment: What is your definition of "shard"?  What is the meaning of "80"?  Is "vitess" some 3rd party software?  If so, add a tag.

Comment: yes @james, vitess is an open source third party framework/tool. Need more reputation to add a new tag.

Answer (score 1):

You're likely getting the error because you still haven't completed the split part of the resharding. You need to first migrate all served types (rdonly, replica and master) to the split shards. After that, you should be able to initiate the merge workflow.